# Headset bearing dimensions

Tags: parts, headset, bearings

I've got some IS49/37 headset bearings on order to be used in a custom frame I'm trying to design, the problem is they take a month to arrive. I don't have a technical drawing of the bearings and can't find one online, I've pretty much finalised the headset assembly parts except from the exact bearing dimensions (height of the chamfer specifically is missing) and I'm too impatient to wait for the bearings to arrive...

Does anyone have the dimensions/technical drawing to hand? Or better yet, if you can point me in the right direction to getting a technical drawing that would be super helpful!

Comment: In the old days, we would go so far as to email (or even phone) the bearing vendor or manufacturer and ask them for such info. :)

Comment: The stack height of different bearings can vary by several milimetres between manufacturers. However, the manufacturer should be able to tell you the stack of the bearing you intend to purchase, as Armand has pointed out

Comment: Offtopic, but how can it take months to deliver a more or less standard component?